# Как добавить conferenceDataVersion в Pyhton, чтобы создать встречу в GMeet с помощью GCalendar?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

Я пытаюсь создать встречу в GMeet с помощью Python и GCalendar. Когда читал документацию, то увидел, что есть переменная, отвечающая за создание встречи, conferenceDataVersion. Я уже пытался объявлять ее в разных местах, но никак не получается. Но программа создаёт обычные события, которые без встречи.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

class GoogleCalendar:
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    FILE_PATH = 'test_email.json'

    def __init__(self):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            filename = self.FILE_PATH, scopes = self.SCOPES
        )
        self.service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials = credentials)

    def get_calendar_list(self):
        return self.service.calendarList().list().execute()
    
    def add_calendar(self, calendar_id):
        calendar_list_entry = {
            'id': calendar_id
        }
        return self.service.calendarList().insert(
            body = calendar_list_entry).execute()
    
    def add_event(self, calendar_id, body):
        return self.service.events().insert(
            calendarId = calendar_id, 
            body = body).execute()


obj = GoogleCalendar()
calendar = 'my_email@gmail.com'

# Данная функция используется единожды
"""
obj.add_calendar(
    calendar_id = 'my_email@gmail.com'
)
"""

# Добавить событие
event = {
    'summary': 'Example Event',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2023-05-26T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2023-05-26T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'conferenceData': {
        'createRequest': {
            'conferenceSolutionKey': {
                'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
            },
            'requestId': 'your_unique_request_id'
        },
        'conferenceDataVersion': 1
    }
}

event = obj.add_event(calendar_id = calendar, body = event)
```